# Django tries to render even commented-out HTML-code which leads to errors

Tags: html, django, django-templates, comments, html-rendering

When rendering a page of my django-project, I get the following error, even though the crucial part of the HTML code is commented-out:

```
NoReverseMatch at /current/
'blog' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/current/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
'blog' is not a registered namespace
Exception Location: /home/user/.virtualenvs/Django3_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py, line 83, in reverse
Python Executable:  /home/user/.virtualenvs/Django3_course/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/home/user/.../todowoo_project',
 '/home/user/.../todowoo_project',
 '/home/user/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts',
 '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python39.zip',
 '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9',
 '/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/.virtualenvs/Django3_course/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:56:35 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/.../todo/templates/todo/base.html, error at line 97

'blog' is not a registered namespace

[...]
```

The commented-out code in question is the following:

```
<!-- <li>
    <a role="button" href="{% url 'blog:all_blogs' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Blog</a>
</li> -->
```

I would like to keep this in case I need to remind myself how to send an URL to another app within my `django` project, in this case called *'blog'*. Why isn't it possible to comment it out, leave it there and let it be ignored by the rendering process?

Even [wrapping it as php-code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26402057/12298276) did not work:

```
<?php
<!-- <li>
    <a role="button" href="{% url 'blog:all_blogs' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Blog</a>
</li> -->
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django template rendering does not care about the HTML, it cares about the {% %}, which is NOT PHP. so enclosing it in PHP blocks won't do anything either.

[How to put comments in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719915/how-to-put-comments-in-django-templates)

has the answer, but '{# comment #}' around your block.

so

```
{% comment %}
<li>
    <a role="button" href="{% url 'blog:all_blogs' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Blog</a>
</li>
{% endcomment %}
```