# how to comment each line with a block comment in html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, comments

I have a HTML fragment like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>text</p>
    <!--  -->
    <p>text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above is just for demostration. Suggest a huge component in the existing comment……

When I select the fragment in `<body>` and press `Ctrl` + `/`, what i expected is

```html
    <!-- <p>text</p> -->
    <!-- <!--  --> -->
    <!-- <p>text</p> -->
```

However, it becomes the code below, even after I disabled all extentions:

```html
    <!-- <p>text</p>
    <!--  -->
    <p>text</p> -->
```

The comment ends at the second line. I tried `Alt` + `Shift` + `I` and [Toggle Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments) Extention, but none satisfied me.

I remember that Microsoft used to add comments as I described above. Why has it changed now? How can I achieve my goal?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401960/how-to-comment-out-a-html-block-which-contains-comments) is a similar question, but not resolved

PS. I know the code I expected also has error. I wonder why it never complained before.